# Android use Animation to change text in TextView refresh only for few frames

Tags: android, animation, textview

I'm using Animation to make a counting TextView from 0 to some value.
But the control refresh only few frames, ie if want to count from 0 to 100, i see the animation only from 0 to 30,  while the LogCat continues to show the verbose output.

```
final Interpolator easing = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
final TextView txtSaldo = (TextView) someView.findViewById(R.id.viewId);
Animation a = new Animation()
{
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        Log.v("----", "time: " + interpolatedTime + " : " + interpolatedTime*fidelityBalance);
        txtSaldo.setText(String.format("%d",(int)(interpolatedTime*fidelityBalance)));


    }
    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return false;
    }
};

a.setDuration(5500);
a.setInterpolator(easing);
txtSaldo.startAnimation(a);
```

I've tried with `txtSaldo.requestLayout()` or `txtSaldo.invalidate()` but no luck.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: you are using custom interpolator 'easing', could you please provide its code?

Comment: nope, easing is simple AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator (edited)

Comment: have you thought about using [TextSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html)

Comment: you know, the problem seems to be in you `willChangeBounds()` callback. I guess, when animation is applied, after several frames text in a textView gets wider, but you forbid changing size, that's why these frames are just dropped.

Comment: Already tried with willChangeBounds = true, but no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by forcing invalidate() to the top, main view container:

```
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        Log.v("----", "time: " + interpolatedTime + " : " + interpolatedTime*fidelityBalance);
        txtSaldo.setText(String.format("%d",(int)(interpolatedTime*fidelityBalance)));

        // top container view
        v.invalidate();
    }
```

maybe the problem is due to other concurrent animations in the view that *finish* while the TextView is still counting.